# How to fix specific uv and recaculate other uv?

Tags: uv

[image]
I want to recalculate only specific areas while keeping certain parts fixed. However, when I pin certain areas, other parts intrude into the pinned area. How can I calculate without this intrusion?

Comment: Just to clarify, the unpinned parts intrude when unwrapped by themselves?

Comment: no. unpinned parts intrude when unwrapped pinned parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the option **Pack Islands** will do it for you?

1. In the UV editor selact all the UV's.
2. From the **UV** drop-down choose the **Pack Islands** option.
3. In the Pack Islands pop-up decide if you want the unpinned islands to be rescaled and or rotated to fit the UV space, set an island margin, check the option **Lock Pinned Islands** and finally hit the OK button.

after a few seconds the unpinned UV's should be re-arranged in the UV space without overlapping the pinned ismand.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That is I want it. I saw tutorial about this. But I couldn't find it. You solve it.